# way to build debian package from Jenkins?

Tags: maven, debian, jenkins

Apparently there is no plugin for building Debian packages from Jenkins, but what would be the best way to do it without a plugin?
Should I just call a shell script as a post build step, which would create the package or is there a more elegant way?

We are developing a Java project which is built using Maven and packed as a debian package using a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [deb-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/deb-maven-plugin/) as part of your Maven build but to be honest if your script is working, I'd stick with that. No reason for it to be a post build step though, you can use the exec-maven-plugin to run your script from within Maven.

Comment: Thanks for the exec-maven-plugin tip!